# How to resolve 500 | Internal Server Error | Doctrine : Base table or view not found: 1932 Table 'table_name' doesn't exist in engine

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, mariadb, symfony-1.4

I have this error :

```
in SF_ROOT_DIR\lib\vendor\symfony\lib\plugins\sfDoctrinePlugin\lib\vendor\doctrine\Doctrine\Connection.php line 1082 ...

                    $message .= sprintf('. Failing Query: "%s"', $query);

                }



                $exc  = new $name($message, (int) $e->getCode());

                if ( ! isset($e->errorInfo) || ! is_array($e->errorInfo)) {

                    $e->errorInfo = array(null, null, null, null);

                }
```

After solving the "Mysql stopped unexpectedly" problem, I've run into the following problem: I can no longer access the tables in my database.